# unable to set the values to a list only last value replacing

Tags: java, list

As you see in the below code, myEntries is a list containing array of strings. It has the below data.

[TestSoftware, Test Sample, AutoTestSoftware11, 1, Concept, Large, java, Medium]

[TestSoftware, Test Sample, AutoTestSoftware12, 1, End of Life, Very Large, java, High]

[TestSoftware, Test Sample, AutoTestSoftware13, 1, Concept, Large, java, Low]

[TestSoftware, Test Sample, AutoTestSoftware14, 1, Concept, Large, java, Critical]

My aim is that as you see, I want to get the number from strings like AutoTestSoftware11 and add 8 to that number. Again, I want to push that whole String Array back into the myEntries. I have posted the output also. The problem I am facing is, Only the last changed value is reflecting in myEntries.

```
List<String[]> myEntries;
String[] world = new String[8];
int t=0;

for (String[] element:myEntries) {
                k=0;
                for (String temp:element) {

                    if (temp.startsWith("AutoTestSoftware")) {
                        int hi = Integer.parseInt(temp.split("AutoTestSoftware(?=\\d)")[1]);
                        hi += 8;
                        temp = "AutoTestSoftware" + hi;
                    }
                    world[k]=temp;
                    k++;
                }
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(world)+"value of t: "+t);
                myEntries.set(t,world);
                t++;
            }
            System.out.println("\n\n");
            for (String[] element2 : myEntries)
            {
              System.out.println(Arrays.toString(element2));
            }
```

**Output:**

[TestSoftware, Test Sample, AutoTestSoftware19, 1, Concept, Large, java, Medium]value of t: 0

[TestSoftware, Test Sample, AutoTestSoftware20, 1, End of Life, Very Large, java, High]value of t: 1

[TestSoftware, Test Sample, AutoTestSoftware21, 1, Concept, Large, java, Low]value of t: 2

[TestSoftware, Test Sample, AutoTestSoftware22, 1, Concept, Large, java, Critical]value of t: 3

[TestSoftware, Test Sample, AutoTestSoftware22, 1, Concept, Large, java, Critical]

[TestSoftware, Test Sample, AutoTestSoftware22, 1, Concept, Large, java, Critical]

[TestSoftware, Test Sample, AutoTestSoftware22, 1, Concept, Large, java, Critical]

[TestSoftware, Test Sample, AutoTestSoftware22, 1, Concept, Large, java, Critical]

Comment: You should be creating a new string array on each iteration, and not re-using `world`. Each element of the List is being set to point to world, which is just a single array in memory. Therefore each element of the list is the same. I suggest you put `String[] world = new String[8];` under the `k=0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain my comment, this works :

```
List<String[]> myEntries;

int t=0;

for (String[] element:myEntries) {
                k=0;
                String[] world = new String[8];
                for (String temp:element) {

                    if (temp.startsWith("AutoTestSoftware")) {
                        int hi = Integer.parseInt(temp.split("AutoTestSoftware(?=\\d)")[1]);
                        hi += 8;
                        temp = "AutoTestSoftware" + hi;
                    }
                    world[k]=temp;
                    k++;
                }
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(world)+"value of t: "+t);
                myEntries.set(t,world);
                t++;
            }
            System.out.println("\n\n");
            for (String[] element2 : myEntries)
            {
              System.out.println(Arrays.toString(element2));
            }
```